Is it ever acceptable for different roots of -i to appear in the same derivation?
I have encountered a derivation which involves the following claims:
First, using the definition of the modified Bessel function
$$(-i)^{\nu}J_\nu(iz) = I_\nu(z)$$
they claim
$$(-i)^{1/3}J_{1/3}(iz) = I_{1/3}(z)$$
$$J_{1/3}(iz) = (-i)^{-1/3}I_{1/3}(z)$$
$$iJ_{1/3}(iz) = i(-i)^{-1/3}I_{1/3}(z) = I_{1/3}(z)$$
which implies the choice of $-i = \text{exp}(i3\pi/2)$ such that $i(-i)^{-1/3} = \text{exp}(i\pi/2)\text{exp}(-i\pi/2) = 1$
Shortly thereafter, they invoke (without proof of any kind) the large argument $z \rightarrow \infty $ form of $J_\nu(z)$:
$$J_\nu(z) \rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{2}{{\pi}z}}\text{cos}(z - \frac{\nu\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4})$$
I studied the proof of this using pg 10-12 of these notes: https://young.physics.ucsc.edu/250/bessel.pdf
In that proof, we have at eq (69) a factor of $(-i)^{-\nu-1}$ where $-i$ is defined as $-i = \text{exp}(-i\pi/2)$ such that $(-i)^{-\nu-1} = \text{exp}(-i\pi(-\nu-1)/2)$
So the definition of $(-i)$ in the main proof is contradicted by the definition of $(-i)$ in a lemma that is implicitly incorporated. Is there any way that this can be regarded as mathematically consistent? I am worried a large section of the main text I am reading is fatally wrong due to this.
I will note that in the large argument Bessel proof, the factor of $(-i)^{-\nu-1}$ arises in a specification of a complex dummy variable t used in a contour integral that defines a representation of $J_v(z)$. Is it possibly okay that we can use different roots of $(-i)$ when in the t complex plane variable versus the z complex plane?
I will also note that in Arfken's Mathematical Methods for Physics textbook, eq (14.99), they define:
$$(-i)^{\nu}J_\nu(iz) = \text{exp}(-i\nu\pi/2)J_\nu(\text{exp}(i\pi/2)z) = I_\nu(z)$$
contrary to what I have encountered above.

To use such roots, you either work in $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R^*_-$ to stay consistent (this is the classical choice for the complex logarithm), and if you have a variable going over bound you need to use a lifting

@julio_es_sui_glace are you describing a branch cut on the negative real axis? I am not familiar with the idea of a lifting.
